# Insert one key frame to all shapekeys in blender

Tags: python

I need a python script to add a dummy keyframe to all shapekeys at one particular frame...
Pls anyone can help me...

Answer (score 0):

##### Insert keyframes to all shapekey values

for active object:

```
import bpy

def add_all_keyframe(obj, attr="value", frame=1):
    if obj.type != 'MESH': return

    blocks = obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks
    if not blocks: return

    for k in blocks:
        k.keyframe_insert(attr, frame=frame)

add_all_keyframe(bpy.context.object)
bpy.context.scene.frame_set(bpy.context.scene.frame_current) #update ui
```

for selected object:

```
import bpy

def add_all_keyframe(obj, attr="value", frame=1):
    if obj.type != 'MESH': return

    blocks = obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks
    if not blocks: return

    for k in blocks:
        k.keyframe_insert(attr, frame=frame)

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    add_all_keyframe(obj)
bpy.context.scene.frame_set(bpy.context.scene.frame_current) #update ui
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response & solution...

Comment: In second case
In line 8 can I change to for obj in bpy.data.selected.objects: to insert keyframe only to selected object?

Comment: @RadhakrishnaRao 
Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum, the answer section is reserved exclusively for answering the OP question, to post comments or replies please use the comments section instead. Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).